# How to compare angles without function atan2?

Tags: geometry

I have angle between two vectors:

```
pseudocode for func angleBetween:
dotProduct = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
determinant = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
angle = atan2(determinant, dotProduct);
```

How to compare

$$\text{angleBetween}(v_1,v_2) < \text{angleBetween}(v_3,v_4)$$

using only determinant and dot product (or other combination) without using atan2 ?

Comment: I have made some modifications in order to improve your title and your text (for example "arcus tangens" is an unknown expression for atan2). Do you agree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of the determinant indicates the orientation of the vectors, while the dot product gives a measure of their alignment. Here's how you can compare the angles using only the dot product and the determinant:

1. Calculate the dot product and determinant for both pairs of vector.\
2. Use the dot product to check if the vectors are pointing in the same direction (dot product > 0) or opposite directions (dot product < 0).
3. If the dot product is positive, use the sign of the determinant to determine the relative angle between the vectors.
4. If the dot product is negative, you'll have to handle the cases where the angle exceeds 180 degrees.

> ```
> # Assuming v1, v2, v3, v4 are vectors represented as tuples (x, y)
>
> def dot_product(v1, v2):
>     return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1]
>
> def determinant(v1, v2):
>     return v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]
>
> def compare_angles(v1, v2, v3, v4):
>     dot_product_12 = dot_product(v1, v2)
>     dot_product_34 = dot_product(v3, v4)
>     det_12 = determinant(v1, v2)
>     det_34 = determinant(v3, v4)
>
>     # Check if vectors 1-2 and 3-4 are in the same direction
>     if dot_product_12 * dot_product_34 > 0:
>         # Compare angles based on determinant
>         return det_12 < det_34
>     else:
>         # Handle angles greater than 180 degrees
>         return dot_product_12 > 0
>
> # Example usage:
> v1 = (1, 0)
> v2 = (0, 1)
> v3 = (-1, 0)
> v4 = (0, -1)
>
> if compare_angles(v1, v2, v3, v4):
>     print("Angle between v1,v2 is less than angle between v3,v4")
> else:
>     print("Angle between v1,v2 is greater than angle between v3,v4")
> ```

This code should give you a way to compare the angles between the vectors using only the dot product and the determinant, without explicitly calculating atan2.
[image]